# Is a gold tag badge holder’s Leave Open/Closed vote binding?

Tags: support, review, badges, tag-badges, dupehammer

If a question is asked, and a user has a gold badge in one of the tags, the gold badge holder can close it as a duplicate as needed. The user can then re-open it with only one vote.

But if someone cast a close vote on the question and you saw it in the Close Votes review queue, and it has a tag in which you have a gold badge, would your Leave Open vote be binding or would other users need to review it?

The same applies to the Reopen Votes queue. Would your Leave Closed vote be binding if it was closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think 'binding' is the correct word here, which is why there is a re-open queue, does not matter who closed the question, it can be reopened by community vote.  There should be several posts about this on Meta already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only moderator reviews are binding. Users with gold badges who make "Leave Open" or "Leave Closed" reviews will not immediately dismiss the review task; it will still have to be reviewed by others.

For the Close Votes queue, it wouldn't make much sense, because the power only works for the *duplicate* close reason, not for other close reasons; the queue is designed to see if questions should be closed for *any* close reason, not just duplicate. As gold badge holders don't have binding close powers when it comes to other close reasons, it doesn't make sense to give them a binding "Leave Open" review there.

For the Reopen Votes queue, it may make sense to give gold badge holders a binding "Leave Closed" review, since the close reason is already given as duplicate. But I think it was left out because it would increase the complexity of the code, since the overall queue doesn't *only* see questions closed as duplicates, but also questions closed for other reasons, where gold badge holders have no binding powers.

Comment: What do you mean by users who originally voted to close a question can’t review...

Comment: @DaniilManokhin If I vote to close a question and it gets closed, and there is a reopen review task generated after the closure, I won't see it in the Reopen Votes queue, and if I access the task via a direct link, it will give me a "This item is not reviewable" message.

Comment: No idea about the re-open review queue, but if you go to the question you can vote to reopen it.

Comment: The answer is correct but it's a bit confusing. The "dupe hammer" only works for duplicate questions not for questions that lack research or are patently off-topic etc.